# ArgumentError File Upload / Import Using Roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet, roo

I am passing the file object into this. 
Controller:

```
RejectLoadsUpload.import(params[:file])
```

Model:

```
def import(file)
  parse_file(file)
end

def parse_file(filename)
  #filename is absolute path
  posts = parse_csv(filename)
  posts.keep_if {|x| x.keys.include? "type"}
  posts.each do |post|
    record = build_record(post)
    #Resque.enqueue(LoadPoster, record)
    #ToTest this uncomment the following line and comment out the above line
    RejectLoads.create(record)
  end

  @log.info "Finished parsing #{filename}..."

  #File.delete(filename)
  #if File.exists?(filename)
  #  @log.error "File #{filename} was not deleted successfully."
  #end
end

# Takes in a file name that is a path to a CSV
#  returns a posts which is an array of array of the parsed file
def parse_csv(filename)
  workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filename.path.to_s, extension: :xlsx)
  workbook.default_sheet = workbook.sheets[0]
  header = workbook.row(1)
  raise EdiLoadsFileEmpty if header.nil?
  posts = []
  (2..workbook.last_row).each do |i|
    post = Hash[header.zip (workbook.row(i))]
    posts.push post
  end
  posts
end
```

I have tried:

```
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filename, extension: :xlsx)
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filename.path, extension: :xlsx)
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filename.tempfile.path.to_s, extension: :xlsx)
```

With and without the extension

Also been trying to use `Roo::Excelx.new` As well with no luck

But i am getting an argument error when it gets to:

`header = workbook.row(1)`

I believe that the error is in the way that i am opening the file.

[image]

```
Started POST "/rejects/import" for 192.168.1.121 at 2015-07-28 13:41:36 -0500
Processing by RejectsController#import as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8zv12AJ4p1cnnWv64c8/N/Nhh0TaMBNZaRzpBgMWcn0=", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb4cf00a8 @original_filename="EDIORD@REJ (4).xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"EDIORD@REJ (4).xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150728-3506-18nzbha>>, "commit"=>"Import"}
        Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 168ms

ArgumentError (ArgumentError):
    app/models/service_objects/reject_loads_upload.rb:34:in `parse_csv'
  app/models/service_objects/reject_loads_upload.rb:12:in `parse_file'
  app/models/service_objects/reject_loads_upload.rb:7:in `import'
app/controllers/rejects_controller.rb:13:in `import'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@loadmax/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@loadmax/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@loadmax/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.4ms)
```

Logs Nothing Here:

```
  workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filename, extension: :xlsx)
  @log.info workbook
  # => <#Roo::Excelx:517603520 @tmpdirs @tmpdir @filename @comments_files @rels_files @sheet_files @workbook @sheet_names @sheets @styles @shared_strings @sheets_by_name @options @cell @cell_type @cells_read @first_row @last_row @first_column @last_column @header_line>
  workbook.default_sheet = workbook.sheets[0]
  @log.info workbook.default_sheet
  # => Sheet1
  @log.info workbook.row(1)  <--- Stack errors here now...
  # => (Blank)   
  header = workbook.row(1)
```

Comment: show us error please.

Comment: I have put all the info there but will upload a image of the error... I modified this post a little to go right to the error...

Comment: no need image please, post  error trace.

Comment: The backtrace shows that the error is in `rejects_loads_upload.rb` in the `parse_csv` method. Please edit your question to include all of the relevant code.

Comment: I know that... I modified my post because it passes the same info thru the methods...

Comment: please try adding log after each step to see what are you getting at each step in parse_csv method

Comment: add the info that you needed

Comment: It's known issue https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/issues/382, please reed comments there